# Unit tests for a cache layer in ASP.NET core Web api where the cache item comes from an outside url

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I am very new to ASP.NET and I am trying to write xunit tests for a cache class.
This cache class is used for get some data and return the data in a web api controller.
The cached data comes from some outside urls, where each cache item has its own cache key.

In my cache.cs class, I have a method called `GetCacheGetOrCreateAsync(... cacheDataSetting)`, and in my controller I will call it to get the data I want. I implemented the cache using `IMemoryCache` class.

There is also a private method in cache.cs called `GetDataByteArrayAsync(string url)`, in which I create a httpclient from `IHttpClientFactory` (it been injected to the cache.cs class level), and returns the outside data get by httpclient.

`GetCacheGetOrCreateAsync(... cacheDataSetting)` calls `GetDataByteArrayAsync(string url)` to get data and then cache it.

Now I want to write unit tests for `GetCacheGetOrCreateAsync(... cacheDataSetting)` (since it's the only public method in this class), and I want to mock the IHttpClientFactory and httpclient, but I'm confused about how can I actually use the mocked httpclient return value since `GetCacheGetOrCreateAsync(... cacheDataSetting)` calls `GetDataByteArrayAsync(string url)` directly. Should I make httpclient a formal parameter for `GetCacheGetOrCreateAsync(... cacheDataSetting)` method? What will be a universal practice for unit testing the cache behaviors?

Thank you!

I have tried to mock the IHttpClientFactory and httpclient, also tried to directly mock IMemoryCache but also found someone suggested we cannot mock cache directly using Moq. Super confused.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your architecture approach. Maybe, there should be some services responsible for the business logic? Then you can wrap the `IMemoryCache` and use it in the services:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

public interface IMemoryCacheWrapper
{
    bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value);

    void Set<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan expirationTime);
}

public class MemoryCacheWrapper : IMemoryCacheWrapper
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public MemoryCacheWrapper(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value)
    {
        return _memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public void Set<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan expirationTime)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(expirationTime);

        MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .AddExpirationToken(new CancellationChangeToken(cancellationTokenSource.Token));

        _memoryCache.Set(key, value, cacheEntryOptions);
    }
}
```

After this, let's inject the cache dependency into your service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCacheWrapper _memoryCacheWrapper;
    private readonly IDataRepository _repository;

    public MyService(IMemoryCacheWrapper memoryCacheWrapper, IDataRepository repository)
    {
        _memoryCacheWrapper = memoryCacheWrapper;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<ItemModel?>> GetCacheItemsAsync(FilterModel filter, CancellationToken token)
    {
        string cacheKey = $"{CacheSettings.CacheKeyPrefix}{filter.Date}";

        if (_memoryCacheWrapper.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out IEnumerable<ItemModel?> cacheResult))
        {
            return cacheResult;
        }

        IEnumerable<ItemModel?> result = _repository.GetSomeItemsAsync(filter.Date, token);

        _memoryCacheWrapper.Set(cacheKey, result, CacheSettings.CacheExpirationTime);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use your services in controllers and easily mock them. Thus, probably there is no need to mock the `IHttpClientFactory` to test your contollers. Please provide the source code and I will try to get a better solution if there are still questions.